# Laravel:How to use composer.json of another project to create a new project

Tags: laravel

I have an exisiting laravel project. I have its composer.json.

I want to create a new larvel project based on that composer.json.

How to do it.

I tried:

Created a new directory. 
Placed the composer.json into it. 
Then i went into that directory and ran composer install. 
It installed all the packages mentioned in the composer.

It has a vendor folder in it and composer.json and composer.lock

Now how to create a laravel project in this folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Composer only installs packages in the vendor directory. Alle other files (such as app, resources etc..) will not get downloaded, because it is not a package.

If you want to use the same packages in a new laravel project, you should install the corresponding laravel version (check the version in the composer.json file) first by cloning or downloading a zip file from github (or use the laravel installer).

After cloning/downloading laravel, update your composer.json to your needs and run `composer update`.

Comment: What i have done is, I ran  `composer update` (first). So presently there is only the vendor directory

Comment: yes. Thats what I meant. You've to install laravel itself from https://github.com/laravel/laravel

Comment: So basically there is no direct command line to create a new laravel project - by supplying it a composer.json file (which has all the details of larvel and other packages). 
Instead you say first i craete a laravel project using `composer create-project laravel/laravel testing "5.1.*"` and then replace the `composer.json` file in it with the desired compose.json and run `composer update` inside the project folder.
It would be nice that using the composer.json, one can create a project and also install all the requirements in the vendor folder.

Comment: Correct. That is, so far I know, the only option.

Comment: Also can i copy the vendor folder to the newly created project. Or  i have to compulsory run the composer update.

Comment: I wouldn't do that, It could give conflicts with the composer.lock/composer.json files. The best way is to just run composer update without a vendor directory.

Answer (score 2):

The framework and the Laravel app folders are 2 completely separate repos. When you create a Laravel project using create-project, it downloads the Laravel project repo, which in turn downloads the framework.

What you want to do if you have made a custom Laravel project you want to use as a starting point is upload that project to its own repo on your service of choice and then clone it and run composer install.